# Eigenvalues and Compact Resolvent

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

For $A$ an unbounded (densely defined) operator on a separable Hilbert space, what conditions on its eigenvalues will show that, for $\lambda \notin $spec$(A)$, we have that $(A-\lambda)^{-1}$ is a compact operator?

Comment: If $A$ is normal, then you need $A$ to have purely discrete spectrum and $|\lambda_n|\to\infty$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $A$ is not normal, the spectrum could even be empty and you wouldn't be able to conclude anything about $(A - \lambda)^{-1}$ being compact.

Comment: @Christian: Great, what is a good (basic) reference for this.

Comment: @User1298: This just follows from the definitions; pretty much any book on spectral theory on Hilbert spaces should have the needed background material. For example Weidmann or Reed-Simon 1.

Answer (score 5):

It is enough that just one among the operators $(A-\lambda)^{-1}$ be compact. Because of the formula
$$(A-\mu)^{-1}=(A-\lambda)^{-1}+(\mu-\lambda)(A-\lambda)^{-1}(A-\mu)^{-1}.$$